# Repeating to the end of an array within a while?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
var_dump(explode(',',$_POST['colum_names']));

echo '<table border="1">';
    $result = $con->query("" . $_POST['sql_command'] . "");
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo '<tr>';
```

**...**

```
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Inbetween the `echo '<tr>'` and `echo '</tr>'` I wish to be able to use the explode array *hard to explain...*

So for example it might look like:

```
$_POST['colum_names'] = a,b,c 
=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }
=> echo '<tr>'; echo $row[array[0]]; echo '</tr>';
=> echo '<tr>'; echo $row[array[1]]; echo '</tr>';
=> echo '<tr>'; echo $row[array[3]]; echo '</tr>';
```

If you get what I mean, I hope you can help!

Comment: `foreach((explode(',',$_POST['colum_names'])) as $value) echo "<td>{$value}</td>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$columns = explode(',',$_POST['colum_names']);

echo '<table border="1">';
    $result = $con->query("" . $_POST['sql_command'] . "");
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach( $columns as $column ) {
            echo '<td>' . $column . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Untested but should work